# Regex to match digits and math operators

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will match this expressions :

```
9+sin(21) 
cos(Pi) 
4+1 
4+5*(2-1) 
6*(3*5*(3*(7*(7-9)-4)-3)-1) 
(120-(2*2*(3*(4-4/4*4)-3)-12/2))*cos(6) 
(-4+1/5*(6+5*2))*9800
```

The regex must dosn't mutch for letters or punctuation symbols

My regex doesn't work:

```
"([(-?\\d+](.*))||"+ "((sin|cos|tan)\\("+"[\\d\\D]{1,5}"+"\\))");
```

Comment: sin/cos/pi are not digits or operators ... even with a whitelist of valid symbols a regex is unlikely to be the correct choice to do whatever your doing (which you have not shared)

Comment: `.*` will match all of those.

Comment: @AlexK. I am already Update the post with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, it works for all your cases, under perl, and won't match letters, except the strings "cos, sin, tan" and Pi.

```
((?:[-\d)(+/*]+)?(?:(?:cos|sin|tan)[(](?:\d+?|Pi)[)])?(?:[\-\d\)\(\+/*]+)?)
```

You could also go with something a bit more complex, if you expect to have more than one occurence of cos/sin/tan.

```
((?:(?:[-\d)(+/*]+)?(?:(?:cos|sin|tan)[(](?:\d+?|Pi)[)])?){1,3})
```

Though with this latter one, you'll need at least 2 occurence, to take into consideration the possible closing ")", if it happens after a string that ends by a cos/sin/tan expression.